# Using json.dumps with ensure_ascii=True

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode

When using `json.dumps` the default for `ensure_ascii` is `True` but I see myself continuously setting it to `False` as:

- If I work with `unicode` I need to pass it or I'll get str back
- If I work with `str` I need to pass it so my chars don't get converted to unicode (encoded within a str)

In which scenarios would you want it to be `True`? What is the usecase for that option?

From the Docs:

> If ensure_ascii is true (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the results are str instances consisting of ASCII characters only.

What is the benefit of it?

Comment: "If I work with unicode I need to pass it or I'll get str back" - you might get a `str` back anyway. `ensure_ascii=False` doesn't promise that the type of the result is `unicode`.

Comment: "If I work with str I need to pass it so my chars don't get converted to unicode (encoded within a str)" - you're turning on the option that allows a `unicode` return value, in the hopes that it will *prevent* you from getting Unicode output? Are you sure you understand what this thing does?

Comment: >>> json.dumps(u"a", ensure_ascii=False)
u'"a"'
I assumed the "return value may be a unicode instance" meant if you pass me unicode I give you unicode but it might not be that. Is there a clear guide of what to pass and what to expect?

Comment: To your second comment: I am setting it to false so if I have str (working with bytes objects) I wont get the failed to UnicodeDecodeError. Ex: json.dumps("\x99")

Comment: The JSON format has no bytestring type; all strings are Unicode, and thus, `json.dumps` assumes that all `str` instances are meant to represent Unicode text, encoded through some encoding. The default encoding is UTF8, in which `'\x99'` is not a valid encoded string. If you want to serialize arbitrary bytestrings to JSON, you should set `encoding='latin-1'` to map the bytes to Unicode codepoints 1-1 instead of changing the `ensure_ascii` setting.

Comment: As for whether the return value is `unicode` or `str` with `ensure_ascii=False`, there are no guarantees, so you should basically just call `unicode` on the return value to guarantee you have a `unicode` object.

Comment: That is quite different from what I expected. But if it works like that, And then I have to check if it is Unicode and decode if necessary every time, wouldn't it just be better to leave it to true and always call decode on the result? (If I want to work only with Unicode on my program)

Comment: The results would be different. With `ensure_ascii=True`, all non-ASCII characters get encoded with `\u` escapes to ensure that all characters in the JSON output are in the ASCII range. You should decide what value of `ensure_ascii` to use based on whether you want that to happen.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Writing up thanks to @user2357112

First thing is to understand there is no binary representation in JSON. Therefore all strings should be valid unicode points. If you are trying to json.dumps raw bytes you might be doing something wrong.

Then check:

- [json docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#basic-usage)
- [Some information about why ensure_ascii works as it works: issue13769](http://bugs.python.org/issue13769)
- `ensure_ascii` does two things. Ensuring your output is valid ascii characters (even if they have unicode inside) and allow the function to return an unicode object.

Which makes me assume that:

- When you are encoding text into json and all your strings are in unicode it is fine to use `ensure_ascii=False`, but it might actually make more sense to leave it to true and decode the str. (As per specification dumps doesnt guarantee unicode back, though it does return it if you pass unicode.
- If you are working with str objects, calling ensure_ascii=False will prevent json from transforming your chars to unicode. You might think you want that but if you then try to read those in the browser for example weird things might happen

About how ensure_ascii impacts the result, this is a table that might help.

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------------------------------+
|         Input         | Ensure_ascii |            output            |
+-----------------------+--------------+------------------------------+
| u”汉语”                | True         | '"\\u6c49\\u8bed"'           |
| u”汉语”                | False        | u'"\u6c49\u8bed"'            |
| u”汉语".encode("utf-8")| True         | '"\\u6c49\\u8bed"’           |
| u”汉语".encode("utf-8")| False        | '"\xe6\xb1\x89\xe8\xaf\xad"' |
+-----------------------+--------------+------------------------------+
```

Note the last value is utf-8 encoded unicode into bytes. Which might be not parseable by other json decoders.

Moreover If you mix types(Array of unicode and str) and use `ensure_ascii=False` you can get an `UnicodeDecodeErrror` (When encoding into json, mindblending) as the module will to return you a unicode object but it wont be able to convert the str into unicode using the default encoding (ascii)

Comment: Hi,  **all strings should be valid unicode points (in Json)** and **Ensuring your output is valid ascii characters (which are going to be writen to a Json file or else)** make me confused: ascii chars are not code points, they are binary, am I mistaken anything?@Mario